# Creating projects in sub-folders [eclipse CDT]

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse CDT for creating the projects. I am creating a workspace and have to create projects in sub directories

```
   + workspace
   |
   +--+ level 1 (folder)
   |  | 
   |  +-- project 1
   |  |
   |  +-- project 2
   |
   +--+ level 2 (folder )
   |  |
   |  +--+ level 3 (folder inside level 2)
   |     |
   |     +--- project 3
```

As per above diagram I have to create project 1 and 2 inside the folder called level1, similarly project 3 inside the folder level 3 ( level 3 folder is inside the folder level2 )

If i try to create the project it says "overlaps the location of another project"

Kindly give suggestions.

Regards
JOhnnie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I have no experience with CDT, but met similar situation with JDT (Java Development Tooling), so my answer may help. In the following, the term `<workspace>`  denotes the root directory of your workspace.

- Eclipse projects want to be created all the time directly in the workspace on top level.
- However, there is an option to select a different location for the project. It should be done like that:

  1. In the project creation dialog, enter the project name.
  2. Deselect the check box "Use default location", and enter manually the directory `<workspace>/level_1/project_1`.
  3. Finish your dialog.
  4. Repeat that process with the following inputs:

     - `<workspace>/level_1/project_2`
     - `<workspace>/level_2/level_3/project_3`
  5. You should now have 3 projects in Eclipse.
  6. When you look at the file system (outside eclipse), you should see the directory structure you wanted to get.
- What is not possible to have projects inside other projects. So `level_1`, `level_2` and `level_3` are only directories, no projects. And they are not visible in eclipse. There are exceptions to that rule (e.g. the m2e plugin for Maven integration into Eclipse), but it has to be implemented by the plugins. I am not aware of a solution for CTS, but I don't know CDT well.

#### Detailed instructions

The following was done in an Indigo installation (Eclipse 3.7) where CDT was added as feature (version 8.0.0).

1. Go to the "C/C++" perspective.
2. Select in the "Project Explorer" `New > C-Project` (should work for C++ as well).
3. Deselect the check box "Use default location".
4. Paste in the Location text box: `<workspace>/level_1/project_1`.
5. Enter into the "Project name": `project_1`.
6. Finish the dialog.
7. As a result, you have a directory structure  `<workspace>/level_1/project_1` and in the project explorer a project name `project_1`.
8. Repeat the step 2 to 5 with the directory `<workspace>/level_1/project_2` and the project name `project_2`.

At the end, you have 2 projects named `project_1` and `project_2`, which lay in the common directory `level_1`. I hope this is now sufficient to recreate it for you.

Comment: If I try to follow the same procedure, I get error "overlaps the location of another project:xxx"

Comment: Added detailed instructions with some more context, hope it works now for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions, I tried the same in indigo, it gives the same problem. I am using indigo (latest with CDT) on windows XP service pack 3.  I get this error "overlaps the location of another project:xxx, though no projects are available in the new workspace.

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question? (Change it!!) At the moment, we were stuck, because you only say "... same problem." Please describe each and every step. Have you followed my detailed instructions, have you started with a clean workspace (empty directory)? Every bit here may make a difference. Without more information, no help is possible :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I have used your procedure, It works fine now

Comment: At least as of Eclipse 4.4.1 you're going to need to "Import" the project after you move it, rather than creating a "New" project [Detailed Instructions, number 2]